# How to get name row as variable in function and plot density graph

Tags: r

I have issues with my function, i don't know if the problem is in the function or in my way to called it.
I have big dataframe with > 20000 row and around 700 columns, with each row a part of a gene and i want to calculate density for each row + plot the density plot with name of the gene.

```
baseM <- read.csv("expansions_full_omim_06_07_21.2.csv", sep = "\t")
rownames(baseM) <- paste(baseM$motif, baseM$chromosome, baseM$intervalle , baseM$gene , baseM$localisation, baseM$OMIM, sep = ".")
baseM.num <- baseM[sapply(baseM, is.numeric)]
names <- rownames(baseM.num.fltr)

d.density <- function(X, n){
#print(X)
d <- density(as.numeric(as.matrix(X)), na.rm=T)
peaks <- NULL
for (i in 2:(length(d$y)-1)) {
  if (d$y[i-1] >= d$y[i] & d$y[i] <= d$y[i+1]) {
    peaks <- cbind(peaks, c(d$x[i], d$y[i]))
  }}

df <- data.frame(test =as.numeric(as.matrix(X)))
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(as.matrix(test)))) + 
       geom_density(fill="#69b3a2", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.8)
ggsave(filename=paste("/work/gad/shared/analyse/STR/Marine/analysis/output/annotation/R_plots/", n, ".png", sep=""), plot=g)
  

#q <- plot(d)
#png(file=file_name)
#print(q)
#dev.off()
return(peaks)
}


baseM.num.fltr$peaks <- apply(temp, 1 , d.density, n=names)
```

I get correctly my peaks but obviously something wrong with the plot. I'm not sure my way to pass the name is correct, or is something else would be better/easier? Thanks for your help! I tried 2 ways for the plot, with or without ggplot2 but not working.

This is the error I get:

```
NULL
Erreur : `device` must be NULL, a string or a function.
>
```

Example of my data :

```
> head(baseM)
                 motif chromosome             intervalle      gene localisation
1 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC       chr2   (69131154, 69132154)     BMP10   intergenic
2 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC       chr2 (237411093, 237412093)     IQCA1     intronic
3 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC       chr2   (44378070, 44379070)    LRPPRC   intergenic
4 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC       chr2 (105218444, 105219444) LINC01102   intergenic
5 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC       chr2 (124310903, 124311903) LINC01826   intergenic
6 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC       chr2   (30730559, 30731559)    LCLAT1     intronic
                                                                                  OMIM
1                                                                                    .
2                                                                                    .
3 .,Mitochondrial complex IV deficiency, nuclear type 5, (French-Canadian), 220111 (3)
4                                                                                    .
5                                                                                    .
6                                                                                    .
  dijen003 dijen004 dijen005 dijen006 dijen007 dijen008 dijen009 dijen010
1       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
2        7       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
3       NA       NA       NA        5       NA       NA       NA       NA
4       NA       NA       NA        5       NA       NA       NA       NA
5       NA       NA       NA        5       NA       NA       NA       NA
6       NA       NA       NA       NA        5       NA       NA       NA
  dijen011 dijen012 dijen013 dijen014 dijen015 dijen016 dijen017 dijen018
1       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
2       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
3       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
4       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
5       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
6       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

(Sorry i know it's a short example but data is really big - and of course not all lines have that much NA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `device` argument, use `png` or `'png'`. (Note that `png()` will work also but only when the filename has the `'.png'` extension.)

(`png()` will work also but only when the filename includes the `'.png'` extension, see comment thread below.)

Example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1L)

df <- tibble(a = rnorm(10))
df %>% ggplot(aes(a)) + geom_density()
ggsave("foo.png", device = "png")
```

[image]

Comment: You can’t use `png()` as the device argument — you *could* use `png` (no parentheses).

Comment: @KonradRudolph `png()` is valid - you can try it with the example above, it works correctly.  From the docs: '`device`  Device to use. Can either be a device function (e.g. `png()`), or one of "eps", "ps", "tex" (pictex), "pdf", "jpeg", "tiff", "png", "bmp", "svg" or "wmf" (windows only).'

Comment: No, it only works because you provided the filename as `foo.png`. Try a different file extension. The documentation is unfortunately misleading: you need to provide a *function*, not a function call expression.

Comment: It's a good point, but the code does execute correctly with `png()` as the device argument.  It's also not sufficient to specify `filename` only in this case, even if it does have the desired extension, so the `device = png()` is not strictly redundant.  Thanks for the observation - I'll make a note in my answer.

Comment: To repeat, the fact that the code works when passing `png()` *in this specific case* is purely by accident. The code is unambiguously incorrect, and the argument is simply ignored: `png()` returns `NULL`, and `ggsave` happens to use this value to infer the device from the file extension. So, contrary to what you’ve said, specifying the filename *is* sufficient in this case, and is exactly identical to passing `device = png()`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I had tested the `filename`-only case before I wrote my comment, and it returned an error.  Running it again, it runs without error.  I must have had another syntax error when I tested it earlier.  Thanks for your persistence - I agree that my earlier statement was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems it solved one part of the problem because it didn't return "NULL" anymore but still it's not working. I'm afraid it's related to my way to pass the name of the row, because if i print the name in the function i just get everything in one loop and after the rest, then obviously i can save the plot correctly :(

Comment: @MarineBergot it'll be easier to help you if you post `dput` of your data, or a subset of it.  it's hard to work with `head`

Comment: @andrew_reece yeah i know but as i told, i have more than 20000 lines and 700 columns, the output 1)almost killed my session and 2) is way too big! except if there is a way for me to attach big file with all the data?

Comment: understood re big file.  you can do `dput` on `head` or on a representative subset that captures diversity in the gene column.  as long as there's enough to demonstrate the various cases that you're trying to solve for (or even a toy dataset that reproduces your issue), it's good to include that in your post.